# Setting different defaultFont to a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel, nimbus

I am using Nimbus look and feel and I have already set a defaultFont like this.

```
NimbusLookAndFeel nimbus = new NimbusLookAndFeel();
nimbus.getDefaults().put("defaultFont", myFont);
```

It works perfectly. But I have a JFrame which comes up with a JButton. And I just want to use different "defaultFont" for the JFrame and all of the components of the JFrame.

But How can I do this ?

Edit: In my JFrame I have tried to override defaultFont value like this.

```
UIDefaults jDefaults = new UIDefaults();
jDefaults.put("defaultFont", newFont);

this.putClientProperty("Nimbus.Overrides.InheritDefaults", Boolean.TRUE);
this.putClientProperty("Nimbus.Overrides", jDefaults);

//SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(this); It doesn't work
System.Out.println(getFont()); // writting myFont instead of newFont
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/_nimbusDefaults.html

Comment: @FastSnail dude I have already use to override nimbus defaults. But I dont think that you got my point. I actually want to use different defaultFont for different JFrames. But I am not sure It is possible.

Comment: @FastSnail It doesn't works :(

Answer (score 0):

After set your font, did you try this:

```
           for(Window window : JFrame.getWindows()) {
            SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(window);
        }
```